# Stopping Animated timing in react native

Tags: react-native

I have created a number ticker like odometer in my react native application. But when I click on the button to start the animation it just goes on. I want to stop the animation after like 5 seconds. Here's the part where I think some modification should be done:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {
      Animated.timing(this.animation, {
        toValue: getPosition(this.props.value, this.props.height),
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start(function onComplete() {
        Animated.timing(this.animation).stop();
      });
    }
  }
```

Running this throws an error like `Cannot read property 'stopAnimation' of undefined`.If I remove the onComplete function it just goes on. So,how can I stop this after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the animation completion callback. It means you are trying to stop something that already ended.

Try

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {
      Animated.timing(this.animation, {
        toValue: getPosition(this.props.value, this.props.height),
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
      Animated.timing(this.animation).stop()
    }
  }
```

You will stop the animation right after starting it.

Comment: It doesn't even start the animation. I want to stop the animation after 5 seconds. @DiogoAleixo

Comment: The first parameter should come from state. Anyway, if `getPosition(this.props.value, this.props.height)` is ok, then you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to stop any kind of animation by calling `setValue()` method and assign a value.
In your case:

```
this.animation.setValue(0);
```

For more details https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvaluexy#setvalue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.animation.stopAnimation();`